# Set up a simple Java package

Tags: java, package

On a Linux [Red Hat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Linux) machine in `/home/user/Downloads/`, I do `mkdir proj`, `cd proj`, and `mkdir lib`.

Now I want to have my Java program residing in the `proj` package, so I have:

```
package proj;
import static proj.lib.Mathem.*;

public class MyJavaApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("abc");
        time = 2013;
    }
}
```

And my library is residing in a `proj.lib` subpackage, so I have:

```
package proj.lib;

public final class Mathem {
    public static long time;
    private Mathem() {}
}
```

If I `cd lib/` and do `javac *.java`, then `Mathem.java` compiles fine into `Mathem.class`, but when I go back `cd ..` and do `javac *.java`, I get an error saying that package *proj.lib* does not exist.

Why does the Java compiler not see such a simple package structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are in the proj directory when it fails.  You need to be in the directory above that, i.e., in /home/user/Downloads in your example.  Then enter "javac proj/MyJavaApp.java"

Answer (score 0):

There is something called [Classpath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29)... I suggest you read up on it

Answer (score -1):

Try adding a public static long getTime() method in Mathem.